# Change "Vote to close" to "Nominate to close"

Tags: feature-request, voting, vote-to-close, terminology

I realized a confusion in the word "voting". Currently, you can either "vote to close", "vote to re-open", "vote to delete", or "upvote/downvote". Refer to a comment of mine on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671667/delphi-install-start-stop-service-inside-application-with-form). I am mentioning "No votes" but my intention was "No upvote/downvote" although I did vote to close. I realize this statement could lead to confusion.

I propose that the term "vote" in relation to closing/reopening should be changed to "nominate" instead. The word still fits, yet is far different from a "vote". Plus, technically a "vote" is performed by a various number of people, whereas a "nomination" is performed by a smaller number of people (in this case 5). This would clear the confusion in the term "vote" so you really know what someone means by a "vote".

I understand the word "nominate" may not be the best fit for this situation, but I generally am aiming for another term than "vote", just to separate the concept of up/down voting from other voting. It could also consist of changing upvote/downvote to something such as like/dislike or even just good/bad.

Comment: /Mumbles something about moderators "nominating" to close...

Comment: Eh, I personally don't think the word "nominate" fits the situation.

Comment: @animuson Yes, that is true, but I'm aiming for some other word than "vote" for this situation.

Comment: The term "close" is being discussed too. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173497/167534.

Comment: The first person nominated, the next person seconded... ? (I don't think nominated makes sense for this).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing changes: \[on hold\], unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sentiment is good, but this might be a potential source of confusion that we just have to cope with.

"Nominate" isn't really the right word, and no other alternatives spring to my mind.  Note that any proposed solution would ideally do natural double duty as noun and verb: "That post has four close nominations," sounds weird.

Changing the term for regular up and down votes is right out.  They're at the very heart of the site, and all the language surrounding them has been carefully honed to produce the brutally efficient Q&A machine that is Stack Overflow.