# Questions closed as duplicate aren't showing the duplicate banner with link

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

This is likely related to the [rollout of the new closing mechanisms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/159251). Duplicate questions here on Meta are missing the headers linking to their master questions:

[image]

[image]

Please fix and then close this as Too Localized...erm, as Off Topic...I guess?

Comment: Looking into it...

Comment: Wait...close as "this has been fixed" really _is_ under "Off Topic"?!  «The problem described here can no longer be reproduced.» That's... _quite_ a stretch.

Comment: Yes, there is, @Josh. If it bothers you, post a [meta-tag:meta-meta] question about it.

Comment: Thanks, @Shog, will do when I get back to a real keyboard.

Comment: @Shog9 META META!