# New close reasons missing a few

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I know that there has been *much* discussion about the new close reasons, and I agree with them fully.. But now there is a problem with certain questions... I will give an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336781/allx-y-bool-object-not-iterable-solved

This question is clearly something that would fit into the old "Too Localized" close reason.

The OP answered his own question, and the answer seems to be that he made a mistake with his imports....

Under the new close reasons - how should this question be close?

Comment: Check under "off topic"--a lot of reasons were moved around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Too localized** was misused because it was too opinion based. Now you have to give a close reason based on analytical thinking and not only emotions.

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe
>   the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it.

seems to be good. You should describe the problem and include valid code, and not include invalid code and write you have a problem.

> Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem
>   being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and
>   how it should work

and than one would be perfect when it's clear that the OP doesn't understand the code (s)he is posting.

Comment: Maybe those descriptions should be slightly expanded.

Comment: Yes, I for me all of them are not very clear. I'm afraid they could be as much misunderstood as too localized...

Answer (score -2):

It probably should not be closed under any of the predefined reasons, since none of them  apply to the specific question. If you really want to close it, you can chose `Off topic --> Other` and add an explanation why you think that it should be closed.

If you chose the "Other" reason, it would be better to use one of the existing reasons listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186088/209087). If a reason is chosen enough times, the moderators will consider to add it to the predefined ones.

Comment: Well. It is pretty much some one dumping their "not-working" code into StackOverflow and asking for help.. then solving it by realizing he forgot to import something.. I *really* don't see how that should stay open?

Comment: Typo-questions, as they're commonly called, are common enough that they SHOULD warrant their own close-reason under off-topic or wherever - not "other".

Comment: I'm sorry but "There is no close reason for it, so it shouldn't be closed." is simply wrong. It just means that the new close reasons are causing way more trouble than they should.

Comment: @FEichinger The moderators are monitoring the custom close reasons. (can't find the link to the relevant question at the moment). If a reason is selected frequently enough, they will add it to the predefined ones.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. My comment was in response to the [original revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/186258/1) of your post, which was worded differently.

Comment: Oops I added the wrong ping :). My previous comment was for @J.Steen

Comment: @FEichinger Yea I changed my mind on that and voted to close the question.