# What does the new on hold mean?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I came across [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184177/c-sdl-game-programming) today that instead of having `[closed]`, it had `[on hold]`. What is this new change, and what does it affect?

[image: On Hold]

Comment: It means they [Closed the loop](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-the-loop-the-closing-overhaul-is-live).

Comment: This is likely to be a question that's asked many times when the new functionality is rolled out on other sites. While it's completely answered at the linked question, "What does 'on hold' mean?" is much more findable and believable as a potential search than "Closing the loop" for this subject. In short, although Cody might have been expected to look around a little, this question _will_ be useful, and I think that downvotes are unwarranted. It wouldn't be the first time a Meta post had been created just to be make information more searchable, either.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Good point. I updated the title on the other question to be a bit more clear.