# After recent changes, close vote options are no longer disabled in the close vote dialog on question you've already voted to close

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

Previously, if you opened the vote-to-close dialog on a question you had already voted to close, you would not be able to select any of the close options.

#### Before

> [image]

With [the new changes to close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons), the vote button is still removed, but the close reasons are selectable. This could be particularly confusing in the case that you quickly select the "off topic" close vote reason: the "you have already voted to close this question" message is no longer visible, so the close button appears to be missing inexplicably.

#### After

> [image]

> [image]

Relatedly, it would be nice if the "You have already voted to close this question" message could be more emphasized. I often skip it without thinking, and have become confused about why I'm unable to vote.

Comment: I assume that -1 means "No, we should be allowed to vote to close questions multiple times"

Comment: And just out of curiousity, if you hit enter from the popup (no focus on the textarea), does the vote submit?

Comment: @ChrisForrence It does not. (They don't have any custom key press handlers and a form won't be submitted when you press enter if it doesn't have a visible submit button.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

If you voted to close a question, when you click `Close` again, you will not get the radio buttons.