# Change the "You have previously voted to reopen this question" shown after retracting your reopen vote to something more informative

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen, wording, error-message

It's now [possible to retract reopen votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410527/13138080) (yay!), but if I try (accidentally or intentionally) to VTR after retracting my vote, it shows this error:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Which tells me nothing about the fact that I've already retracted my vote; just that I've previously VTRed.  Can we change it to something more relevant, such as the:

[image]

for comments, e.g:

> You've already retracted your reopen vote on this question; you cannot vote to reopen again

This should also apply to CV-ing a question, as it shows the same toasty message, but with a few differences.

Comment: Similar (for VTC): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200397/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184206/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332817/282094