# FAQ link still visible under "Off Topic" close vote description

Tags: bug, meta-faq

Under the "Close" dialog as well as the explanation below a closed question:

> Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or
>   software development within the scope defined in the FAQ. Consider
>   editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you
>   believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read
>   more about closed questions here.

I understand that the links forward to the appropriate help center page, but it's still incorrect.

Comment: [All of the close vote reasons are going to be changed in just a few days anyway...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/186381)