# Minimum length of free-text off-topic reason is too long

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, close-reasons

When I use the new *vote-to-close* dialog on meta and want to add my own free-text off-topic reason then I have to enter at least **30 characters** to the existing sentence.

I think this is too much. I would only add 1 or 2 words to the sentence already displayed. And if I want to add my completely own desciption it has to be at least **88 characters**.

Please reduce that to a lower limit.

[image: Closing]

The example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) is exactly 88 characters long:

> Your question appears to be about 'Cat Grooming', which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

But I don't think that all other free-text reasons have to be at least so long.

Comment: I agree that we should reduce this. Maybe down to 15 more characters to start and then see how that feels?

Comment: Or just not introduce any new limits and make these behave like normal comments (i.e. at least 30 characters long).

Comment: @AnnaLear: I like your second suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're going to drop the length requirement to 30 characters altogether. We'll still provide the "This questions appears to be off-topic..." template, so all people will need to do is finish the sentence somehow.

There *is* a risk of people being too abrasive or cryptic in these, but minimum comment length isn't a guarantee that folks will be nice or coherent either. We are going to be monitoring the kinds of custom comments that people leave when closing, so if this ends up being abused, we can bump the requirement up again and/or do something else depending on how things go.

Comment: Any news on when the new close stuff is coming to main SO?

Comment: Yes. But telling you might jinx it. So, soon. BEWARE!

Answer (score 0):

The three canned off-topic reasons are 212, 207 and 212 characters respectively. If a user is going to provide a custom off-topic reason, it seems reasonable that the explanation be at least as detailed as the canned reasons.

There is a danger that extremely short close reasons are also cryptic. For this reason, I vote that the current limit stay in place to encourage close-voters to provide clear, complete explanations.

Comment: Being forced to enter 88 charatcers when you can get to the point in less is just not user-friendly. Or can you surely say that there is no reasonable close reason less than 88 characters?

Comment: @juergend The experience of having a question closed is not very user-friendly either. A good way to improve that experience is to provide complete details about what went wrong and how to fix it. If that means close-voters need to type a bit more (or maintain a list of copy-pasteable canned reasons) in order to provide the best information available, it seems like a good trade-off.

Comment: And at 88 characters the *best information available* start?

Comment: @juergend The line is arbitrary, naturally. I'm simply saying that more verbose is likely to be better than less, and using the canned close reasons as a guideline for "how much is enough."