# Explanation of MSO close-dialog tag text

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta

The explanatory text for the MSO [close-dialog](/questions/tagged/close-dialog) tag describes it in terms of the dialog presented to >=3k users for closing, but this same dialog is for the most part also presented to those with >=15 rep when they flag. Since there is no comparable [flag-dialog](/questions/tagged/flag-dialog) tag and since the flagging population is so much larger, I think it's worth revising the text to comprehend both.

(Note: This didn't seem like a "feature request", but the definition for the "bug" category seemed to require that it be related to programming errors, so I chose this category as the least ill-fitting.)

Comment: So, why don't you propose an edit?

Comment: I hope I don't get shot, but I created the [meta-tag:flag-dialog] tag.  Since the dialogs are different (sort of), I thought it would be useful

Comment: @psubsee2003 Then better identify a series of posts that need the tag.

Comment: @Bart I needed something to do tonight

Comment: @Bart - I would have and will, but my experience with MSO so far as is that there are usually lots of reasons put forward (and lots of corresponding downvotes) for keeping things "as they are" and I'm reluctant to put much effort into proposing a change without understanding the opposing view(s).

Comment: Since >xk features are only visible to >xk users and documentation is spotty, I'm not in a great position to compare the flagging dialog to the close dialog, but my sense is they are close enough (no pun intended) that they should share the same tag.

Comment: @psubsee2003 By the way, we do already have a [meta-tag:flagging-dialog] tag.

Comment: Hmmm, so we have `close-dialog` but not `flag-dialog` and `flagging-dialog` but not `closing-dialog`. Is there a reason for the difference in verb tense?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Just the way that users created them. I'll probably rename it to [meta-tag:flag-dialog] at some point so that it matches.

Comment: @animuson oy vey.... I guess a tag synonym is probably in store.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Created :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do have a [flagging-dialog](/questions/tagged/flagging-dialog) tag here on Meta. You really should use that tag when you have questions about the **dialog box itself** when flagging, even when flagging to close. The close dialog that appears within the flag dialog for lower-rep users *is* slightly different, most noticeably in the off-topic sub-list where the "other" option is missing. It doesn't make sense to tag those questions with the [close-dialog](/questions/tagged/close-dialog) tag.

Having said that, *only* use the **-dialog* style tags when your question **is actually about the dialog box itself.** That includes how the dialog box appears to users, how users interact with it, and other general things about the actual dialog box.

**If your question is about**

- the reasons you are presented with in the flagging dialog, use [flag-reasons](/questions/tagged/flag-reasons)
- the reasons you are presented with when voting to close / recommending closure, use [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons)
- the process of flagging in general, use [flags](/questions/tagged/flags)
- flags in the history of your past flags, use [flagging-summary](/questions/tagged/flagging-summary)
- the process of voting to close questions in general, use [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close)
- questions which are closed in general, use [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions)
- a closed question you'd like reopened, use [reopen-closed](/questions/tagged/reopen-closed)

---

Your [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193617/scope-and-wording-of-minimal-understanding-of-the-problem-close-category) was not about either the close dialog or the flag dialog. That question is regarding one of the off-topic close reasons, and your understanding of it. The proper tag combination there is [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) and [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic), indicating that you want to discuss the off-topic close reasons (or in this case, a specific one).

Comment: Impressively comprehensive answer. I'm going to study now.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I've also updated the [close-dialog tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/close-dialog/info) to provide more information on this.