# If there is an old question and I have something to add how should I go about it?

Tags: discussion, meta, old-questions, feature-request-process

In this case I am talking about [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/allow-cross-posting-of-questions-to-more-than-one-so-site/13802) on MSE.

The feature request was last active 2 years ago and 610 people have seen it. I think that this question had too small an impact and I consider this topic important.

I upvoted it, so far I am clear.

What should I do now?

- Should I post a new question/feature request that is similar (I do not think I should)?
- Should I comment it (which will probably not change its impact drastically)?
- Should I give another answer with my example? 
  *(Basically I have another example of a question that might make sense to be posted on https://security.stackexchange.com/ as well as on https://stackoverflow.com/. It is a security related programming question: "Can I replace all system calls in the system call table on forking?". Now I know I will reach many more people who might know about this on Stack Overflow, but I think it makes more sense to post it on security.stackexchange because of the details of the question and the security implications that interest me very much.)*

Also I feel like doing something wrong by reviving it (e.g. annoying people).

*Sidenote: is meta.stackexchange.com the right place to be discussing this?*

Comment: Or worse, what of a very old answer, that I feel like downvoting. I'd consider it unfair to downvote something that has been written years ago. Or might it create value for the community anyway?

Comment: If you feel a contribution isn't helpful then downvote it and in the case of a meta answer or question if you disagree with the contribution downvote it. It doesn't matter old the contribution is, if it's not helpful, it should be downvoted

Comment: Cross-posting a question to multiple sites itself is acceptable in certain condition: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231885/should-strictly-on-topic-cross-posts-be-put-on-hold-as-off-topic. Considering that each question usually has to be tailored to each site, allowing cross-posting *an exact verbatim question* might be very rare and doesn't need a feature-request though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to feature requests generally tend to be "I think this is a good idea because ..." and sometimes include suggested details. For example if a badge is suggested, answers might suggest names for it, or refine the criteria. Or they may be "I think this is a bad idea because ...". Both kinds of answers may include links to examples.

In looking at the existing question, if you see an answer you entirely agree with, other than it is missing a link to a new example question, there is no point adding another answer. You could add a comment with another example. As you point out, this won't bump the question or get it more attention. If you don't see any answer making your point (unlikely, the point that SO gets way more eyeballs than the smaller sites is not new) you could add one. Or if you have an idea for how to do this that would overcome the objections you see in comments or answers, you could add an answer laying out that idea.

And you always have the options from [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions) even though the question is answered. Add a bounty. Share it on twitter or your blog or whatever. Maybe edit it, but do that with caution. Do not:

- edit your comment (eg "another example of this is ...") into the question. That goes against the author's intent
- make a trivial edit (switch two sentences, add a few line breaks, format something in bold) just to get the question bumped to the front page
- edit in the word "bump" or "any update on this guys?" or "Edit: it's been a long time, what's happening with this?"

I know, that sounds like "don't edit" but maybe the reason the feature-request didn't go anywhere is that the question and its answers were hard to read (spelling, grammar, punctuation, capitalization) and if you can fix that, perhaps it will find a more receptive audience the second time around.