# "Blatantly off-topic" close reason incorrectly rendering link

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, meta

While flagging a question, I noticed that the "blatantly off-topic" close reason wasn't rendering the link to https://stackexchange.com/sites properly

[image]

I assume that it's supposed to be just like how "network" is a link in the close reason above it. Can we get it fixed?

Comment: Wait, that's a thing now? I wasn't aware that a new reason was added... isn't that the same as the "does not appear to be about SE" reason above?

Comment: @Doorknob: might there be some use for distinguishing among marginal and "blatant" cases (e.g., statistical analysis)? Regardless, I had the same reaction when I discovered it an hour or two ago...

Comment: Some Community Manager had a bad day? The only explanation I can think of. Will there be more degrees of off-topic-ness?

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY yep, it's [Shog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185873/152859)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see. That proposal was about SO all the way, but somehow   spawned an extraneous reason for meta.SE. Maybe the stress of data center move got to SE people. The bug in this thread isn't the URL, it's the existence of that item.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY nope, it's not specific to Stack Overflow, e.g. on http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ it says "Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with gaming)" so it's just a typo on their side here in MSE. Cool, found a bug in gaming site, thanks! ;)

Comment: @JoshCaswell that's because you have over 3K rep so it's becoming a close dialog (the "Other" is what this is all about). Try on a site where you have less than 3K rep and you'll see it.

Comment: Where did you see it? [I don't see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9xLwr.png)

Comment: @nicael not close dialog, flag dialog. See the caption "Flagging" in the screenshot here, vs. your caption which is "Closing".

Comment: Oh, gotcha, @ShadowWizard.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The *proposal* was to add this reason on SO. And I think the underlying problem was that SO somehow lost the ["plain" offtopic reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193668/): "does not appear to be about {site subject} within the scope defined in the help center". Other sites had this reason all along, and adding "blatant" to them is redundant.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY I agree, but Shog appears to be quite firm on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2014.6.10.2300` on meta and `2014.6.10.1649` on sites.

Comment: Think it's only affecting MSE.