# Flag for 'Write this Code' (Feature Request)?

Tags: feature-request, flags

I have come across quite a few question of people asking basically 'Can you write this code for me', and there seems to be no flag for it (I do use an existing flag and flag them, however I would like a new one to be added).

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193451/312833) answer, I should flag them as Off-Topic, however when I click on Off-Topic, I get a few sub-options:

**Questions about general computing hardware**... Not here

**Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration**... Nope

**Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial**... It is not really under this, since the user is not asking to find software, but *make* software

**Questions seeking debugging help**... No

**This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced**... Not under this category

**Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)**... Well, it doesn't have *nothing* to do with programming

**This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network**... No

As you can see this sort of problem does not fit under any of these categories.

I suggest be have another flag, under Off-Topic, for "Asking for a Coding Service"

Comment: Druzion, please stop suggesting edits until you've learned more about this site.

Answer (score 5):

The flag you should use is either "Unclear what you are asking about" or "Too broad".

The first option is probably the better option since the post has no question and you have no idea what to answer. "Too broad" is also an excellent flag because there are lots of ways to achieve the OP's needs to finish the code. It isn't really off-topic because as you said, it doesn't fit in any of the categories.

Best options: "Unclear what you are asking about" or "Too broad"

This answer supports the "Too Broad" option: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193439/278543 , while experience and lots of helpful flags support the other option.

So the new option isn't really needed here. You have like 3 different options (more like 8 if you count the sub-options for off-topic) to flag/close a question that fits your description.

Comment: Okay, thanks for telling me that, however "Unclear what you are asking" doesn't really fit. However this was mainly a feature request

Comment: I edited my answer