# Break "off topic" close reasons into specific reasons in Tools rather than grouping them in one bucket

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, off-topic, 10k-tools

The 10K user tools are really great!  Recently I was attempting to get an idea of which close reasons are used more than others...

[Currently only applies to off topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210314/categories-other-than-off-topic-should-allow-custom-close-reasons), most sites have between 3-6 off topic reasons plus the custom close reason.

This means that when you sort close votes by close reason, "off topic" is often the top reason... but as that linked topic points out... many sites have reasons that aren't actually "off topic" in that list, they're just hampered by not being able to use custom reasons anywhere else.

Would it be feasible for SE to sub-sort the "off-topic" list by the actual close reason? I feel that this would be very helpful when trying to see a recent snapshot of closed questions.

I understand that this may require creating a "short name" field for the close reason that will fit into the UI.

---

As a note, I'd also be interested in seeing if a SEDE query can even group by close sub-reasons and, if not, it that was a possibility as well.

Comment: Related: [Please add the individual close-as-off-topic reason in the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297750/please-add-the-individual-close-as-off-topic-reason-in-the-data-explorer).