# What to do when reviewing clueless/lame questions?

Tags: discussion

After several years on the site, I've recently start to review questions and answers when I have a few moments here and there.

I have to say I am *stunned* at how many stupid questions are asked on this site everyday!  I'm not saying this to sound smart or anything, I just am actually overwhelmed by it.  It's not that the new user is not asking a question, or that its off topic or too broad, its that you can tell by reading the question that they are SO lost they are beyond help in a Q&A forum.  They really need to read books or take classes or something.

Many seem to have just typed in the question from a test or quiz or something like that and except people here to completely answer them.

I feel like there needs to be a new category for closing a question which is that the questioner does not exhibit enough domain knowledge in question for it to be answerable.  Or that the person lacks the knowledge to ask a decent question or something.

In the meantime, what's the best thing to do?  Some of the time I leave comments...other times I vote to close.  If somebody actually took the time to write up a long explanation, I downvote the question, upvote the answer if it is helpful and vote the leave the question open.  Just looking for standard practices here.

**Edit:**

Here are some examples, although they are not nearly as bad as the ones I saw earlier today:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437504/how-to-create-a-page-automatically-according-to-table-data

[Reset milliseconds to zero every 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437869/reset-milliseconds-to-zero-every-10-seconds)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437729/html5-javascript-form-to-create-new-webpage-form-on-website1-com-makes-web

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437575/good-free-alternative-to-jqgrid-for-mvc-and-ef

Comment: If you had specific, pointed examples, then that would help. In all honesty, though, I don't find half of the questions here stupid or clueless - if they need time to research it, then there are close reasons that adequately cover that (minimum understanding, highlight specific problem, etc).

Comment: Where are those close reasons that you mention?  I must have overlooked them....

Comment: @HDave "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking." | "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." | "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself." et cetera et cetera; they were added a couple months ago.

Comment: @Emracool - OK, I just found those...thanks.  I missed them because they are subcategories under "Off Topic".  I assumed off-topic mean that the question wasn't a software development question.  Perhaps another top level category like "Malformed Question" or something could help.

Comment: @HDave, a large portion of the community completely agrees with you that these close reasons *really* don't belong under "off topic", but nobody with the power to fix this actually cares. There have been at least a dozen questions/answers on meta of people asking to have this changed. This is probably the biggest one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic

Comment: I agree with the posting, however, I found that there are also a lot of questions where the poster has shown some effort but are missing some small stuff. In such cases, I find the answer "question must demonstrate some understanding" a bit rude. Another option like "Question needs additional information" would be helpfull in such cases, also to tell the poster that he indeed can improve the question by adding the missing bits, instead of getting the impression "go and study first"

Comment: @Devolus -- 100% agree

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use appropriate close reasons for these. There was [a recent overhaul of the close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons). Now, they include reasons like:

> **off-topic**: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://ssccee.org) for guidance.
>
> **off-topic**: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
>
> **unclear what you're asking**: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
>
> **too broad**: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

There are a couple other close reasons, but these are the ones that apply to your question. The first two in particular apply to the types of questions you've explicitly stated, but the other two may also be useful. Use your best judgment, as always.

Comment: Sometimes you can also use the "Other" reason and write there what's wrong if none of the above matches well.