# New close reason - Allow to vote to close a question based on "info is in help center"

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, help-center

### Proposal:

I think it would be very worthwhile implementing a new close option:

Vote to close based on:

> The question being asked already has an answer within the help center.

And link to the help center, much like with the close due to duplicate where there's a link to the dupe, the new option to *close based on help center info* would allow you to choose/paste/search a link to a help center topic.

### Example:

A user asks the question *"How do the bounties work? What do I have to do to place one?"*. Instead of finding a duplicate answer somewhere, why not link to the help center?

### Benefits:

- The user potentially learns more - The user with the question being directed to
  the help center means they may peruse the help center and learn about
  the site, potentially avoiding them raising another question next time they have one;
- More accurate - The help center is more likely to be updated with
  changes/new content etc than an old question which may have multiple
  dupes linking to it;
- It looks more professional to link people to the site's own info in the help center than *users'* previous questions. ie "this is Stack's help center" rather than "hey, someone else asked this, here's that users question";
- Generally sending more users towards the help center and having more
  links around the site linking to the help center within various questions
  opens the potential that more users will read and make use of the help center, rather
  than asking or searching questions;

### New close popup reason and subsequent options:

### Close Reason

[image: close reason]

---

### Help Center

[image: help center]

Answer (score 6):

There shouldn't be a new close reason as it would then have to apply on all sites, but instead it would be more appropriate to add it as another custom off-topic reason, since this would be meta specific.

However despite the value of sending users to the help center, everything in the help center is also reflected somewhere else on Meta, specifically in the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag. You would theoretically be able to close any question with this close reason as a duplicate of an existing meta post, so this reason would be redundant.

Additionally the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post is often going to contain more information than would be in the help center, so closing as a duplicate would be better in many of these cases.

Comment: It being another off topic reason is not right. It's not off topic to ask about bounty, it's just been asked before, so either "dupe" or "in the help center" as per my suggestion. There are already debates about the off topic thing, as I and others don't think many of the off-topic things are really off topic in the real (and generally accepted/known) definition of off topic, just Stack's definition of off topic. But I can see no-ones going to change their mind on that so meh. Was just an idea as I thought the help center was supposed to be Stack's, well, help center, to avoid people asking.

Comment: @James The point that I'm making about being off-topic is the 5 main close reasons are uniform on all sites.  There are no site-specific customization.  That is what the custom close reasons are for and they are grouped under off-topic.  If the SE team would decide to implement this, it would have to be a custom reason for meta sites since it is only appliciable to meta (both the per-site Metas and MSO/MSE).

Comment: Fair point. But each site has it's own help center which could be linked to. So my feature would be a top level close reason on all sites, and then when users voted to close, the link they chose to the help center would be a link to the help center for the site which the question is situated. (maybe I don't yet understand the bigger picture..)

Comment: @James but still only applicable to the site's meta.  An appropriate question for this close reason asked on it's main site would legitimately be off-topic and should likely be migrated to its meta.

Comment: Right, so a question "how do I do bounty" would be migrated from SO to MSO, then voted to close as "this already has an answer/info in the help center"?

Comment: @James but the close reason would still be on the main site because it is part of the main close reasons.  Questions like that off-topic on that site, so it isn't appropriate to have it as a close reason.

Comment: @James Many sites' custom off-topic close reasons include reasons that are not about something being off-topic. The official answer is that [off-topic is not only about off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic). It's unfortunate, but the problem isn't limited to MSO.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think this is a good idea. There are probably dozens, if not hundreds, (or thousands, depending in the size of the site) of Meta questions that have an answer somewhere in the Help Center. The whole point of Meta (besides setting and disputing policies) is to ask questions about how the site works and how it should work. Closing such questions seems like subverting the purpose.

Instead, when someone asks a question about how the site works, someone should post an answer. If the answer is based on information in the Help Center then cite that information in the answer with a link to the Help Center. Especially when it comes to Site specific issues, most of the content in the Help Center is itself derived from Meta, so you can skip the middleman and link directly to the relevant Meta post (though citing the Help Center might look more official/authoritative than a Meta post).

When future questions get asked on the same topic, simply close them as duplicates of the original.

I don’t think there is a need for a new close reason.