# Meta question that has an answer in help center

Tags: support, per-site-meta, help-center

From time to time I see questions on ruSO meta (I think that any other metas have the same situation) when user asks something about site, and there is an answer in help center.

What should we do in such case:

- Just post a link to help center page in comment section?
- Post an answer that content is mostly copied (or rephrased) from the help center page with a link to help page?
- Retype entire help center as a [faq] tagged question on meta, and close new questions as duplicates?
- Something else?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213145/new-close-reason-allow-to-vote-to-close-a-question-based-on-info-is-in-help-c

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog I expected a link to help center page :)

Comment: How often does this happen?  And is it coming from a range of users, or from one particular user?  It may be a bit subjective, but for myself it doesn't seem like that much trouble to write an answer largely based on the help centre page once or twice a year, but if it's once or twice a month, perhaps it's something that needs dealing with.  If it's coming from a particular user who is repeatedly (I mean, lots of times, not twice :) ) writing questions just to get upvoted questions on meta, flag for mod attention.

Comment: @anonymous2 It happens fairly often on MSE, but in most cases there's also an FAQ that can be used as a dupe target.

Answer (score 6):

I'll suggest that you quote and link to the relevant part of the Help Center and add any additional information that may tie to the specific case of the question asked.

Our Help Center articles are designed to be pretty broad and not get too deep into edge cases; that's what our FAQ articles are for. Because of this, someone asking a question may get most of what they need from the Help Center article but not all of it. In many cases there's something small that might change the general answer.

Even if that's not the case, quoting the Help Center and restating the information that specifically relates to the question in an answer and linking to the Help Center is the right course of action. This has two benefits.

1. The information is now on Meta - this isn't a bad thing. We don't index the Help Center in search, so if people are unaware of the HC, it can get missed easily.
2. There are more links to the Help Center, which means more people may realize it exists and use it.

Both of these are good! Our poor Help Center has tons of information but is little-used because we don't make it really easy to find.

If the question is broad enough that it encompasses most of what's in the Help Center article, feel free to turn the entire question and answer into a FAQ but don't feel like the answer needs to specifically mirror the HC... we generally expect FAQs to be more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget the Help icon contains a link to the Help Center for whatever stack* site you are viewing, and this will include sections specific to that site.  For example stackoverflow's FAQs includes a section on Teams. In some instances, where the question clearly asks that such information be made more available, showing an image of the Help Center link in the dropdown Help menu can reinforce your message with a vivid access point.

For example;

[image: meta.stackexchange.com] & [image: stackoverflow.com]