# Off-topic Review Messaging

Tags: support, review, off-topic

When reviewing 'off-topic' questions to 'close', the box at the top asks:

> Should this question be closed as: **off-topic** (more)

Clicking on `(more)` causes a drawer to open, with the following message:

> **off-topic:** This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange
>   network

However, at least two of the 'off-topic' reasons ('describe the specific problem' and 'minimum understanding') indicate the question is off-topic for a reason that would make them off-topic for all S.E. sites. I'd propose cleaning up the language here and bringing it into line with the more general stance of the 'off-topic' close reason, thus alleviating confusion - especially for new reviewers.

Comment: Oh, the [can of worms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086) you just (re)opened.

Comment: I saw that, but I'll note that I am suggesting something distinct from that; specifically that the language in this place comes into line with the broader idea of off-topic, not that we change what is in off-topic's list of sub-categories. For instance, "This question does not belong on this Stack Exchange site due to form or content."

Comment: It's not just that.  The two close reasons that you cite as making a question generally unsuitable for the entire network are actually specific to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realized that (I only review on SO). Are all of those first five sub-reasons specific to SO?

Comment: The five site-specific close reasons for Stack Overflow are listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Perhaps it should suggest that the question doesn't belong on stack overflow, rather than that it does belong elsewhere.