# Can a complaint at a Meta site be ever 'off-topic'

Tags: discussion, meta, off-topic

Is it possible, by the current rules, that a *complaint* about bullyism and vandalism is closed because it is deemed 'off-topic' by five regular users.

I suppose it can only be declared ungrounded but not 'off-topic'. Moreover  shouldn't such a delicate decision be left only to appointed mods?

Is this site where I am writing the question on the same footing of all meta sites, or is it on a superior level? To whom should one apply to in order to get a fair response?

Comment: It might be worth adding an example. One off-topic reason is "This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community" so something that's a rant and not seeking advice or proposing a change might fall into that category.

Comment: Plain rants that do not seek feedback are off-topic, yes. If a post comes *just to complain* there isn't much we can do; Meta is for discussions, not a customer service complaints box to deposit grievances into.

Comment: *"Is this site where I am writing the question on the same footing of all meta sites, or is it on a superior level?"* Not so much superior, but rather specific to network-wide issues. *"To whom should one apply to in order to get a fair response?"* The community, which includes everyone from users to moderators and employees.

Comment: Possibly helpfully related: [Shouldn't "off topic" be only about...off topic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic)

Comment: +1, that's a valid discussion with interesting possible answers.

Comment: Nope, I'm doing my best to keep the site clean, in my standards. The fact you don't agree with those standards does mean you're right.

Comment: It's not about rue words, you added noise to your question, things that might fit in comments or chat, but not as part of a question. I just insist on removing that noise. At some point a moderator (SE employee here on MSE) would come over and put an end to this, one way or another. If I'll be told by that employee to stop editing, I will stop.

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely it's possible. Say you believe that correcting `u` to `you` is vandalism, and that nobody should edit your posts under any circumstances. If you come to a meta site and ask "How can I stop these edits" you will get answers: you can't, that's how the site works, etc.

However, with the exact same complaint if you post on meta about your right to use `u` and how everyone is bullying you, people may decide you don't have an actual question or discussion topic, you're just ranting. Further, if you don't include links or background, they may not even be able to figure out what you're ranting about in the first place. This will likely lead to being closed for not seeking input from the community or not being about the site itself - in other words, off topic.

Should this happen to you the key is to **edit your question** so that it is about the policies or mechanisms of the site, and so that it is an actual question. If you include a link to one of your closed questions here, I'm sure there are folks who could take a look and give you some advice.

Answer (score 7):

Discussions (let's face it, complaints are discussions, with a slightly more focused agenda) on meta sites really need only two characteristics to be on-topic:

- They need to be *about* the site, or the software that powers it in some way
- They must look to accomplish something, they need to be constructive

If your complaint is *this thing is happening to me, and I'd like it to stop*, then it's valid the first time that you toss it out. The community might very well respond by letting you know that this sort of thing is expected, but it's *not* expected to upset you.

At that point, you're fully within bounds to come back to the community with something like *"I know that [thing] is expected, but I found it unsettling, and I propose we do [other thing] instead"*. Then, go on to explain what you'd like to change, your idea for how it could be better, caveats that might need resolving, and any thoughts on the matter.

The community will then decide what it wants to do. It's *not* terribly uncommon for some folks in the community to find themselves strongly at odds with certain accepted norms. I personally find it ridiculous that I can't ask someone to recommend a software library that accomplishes something very specific on a site for programmers, but constantly bringing that up without anything *new* would just be considered noise.

The process, however, is not without appeal. If you think that something a community is doing is *very* harmful, and as if you're the only one that can see something on fire, then you're welcome to [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) to talk about it. If whatever concerns you is *truly* a real threat to a community moving forward, there's a good chance that we're already talking about it.

Comment: Thanks, Tim, That is a precious link, if an abuse has really been committed, can people at this link redress it? Is the link the same as to the 'community managers'?

Comment: @bobie Yes. That form goes to us (the community team). We'll do our best to address whatever is going on, though sometimes that just means doing our best to explain it. Continuing my example, if folks write to me complaining that their quest to find a library was marked off-topic,  the best I can do (right now) is explain the history, how we arrived at that point, that everyone is just doing their best to keep the site great, and that new ideas are always welcome. But yes, if you feel really frustrated and unheard, we definitely need to hear from you.