# After reading the meta I still don't know where to post my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-recommendation, off-topic

I posted a question on Programmers and was told that I should post it on Stack Overflow instead.

Having posted it in both places, both questions are now **"on hold  as off-topic"** so really, I don't know where I'm supposed to post this question anymore.

[Question on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/268189/returns-parameter-value-in-comments-doesnt-display-in-intellisense)
[Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799689/returns-parameter-value-in-comments-doesnt-display-in-intellisense)

I added a little more info to the SO question to follow what the "off-topic" notice suggestion but I seriously doubt it'll ever receive any attention again.

So where can I post this question now that the 2 most likely places have rejected it outright?

Comment: I might be understanding it wrong, but SO's off-topic list [is arguable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic). The question is not "appropriate" (for lack of a better word) on Programmers, but it should be acceptable on SO assuming you follow the instructions in the close reason, which looking at your edits and reopen votes, you seem to have done.

Comment: I also suggest this post be moved to MSO, as it deals more directly with SO.

Comment: One slightly off-topic suggestion here too - if you post on one site and are told in a comment that your post belongs on `site x` then check the commenters profile to make sure they have some rep on the suggested site. If they have >1k then they probably know what they're talking about. If they have ~1 rep score then don't listen to them because they wouldn't know what is/isn't suitable for the suggested site.

Comment: If you ever find yourself uncertain of where to ask a question *before* you ask it, you can summarize the question here, on MSE, and tag it [tag:site-recommendation].

Answer (score 12):

Stack Overflow is indeed the correct place, since this question is about Visual Studio which is a commonly used IDE for programmers.

It was put on hold not because it's off topic to Stack Overflow in concept, but because you failed to provide enough details.

Since you added such details I've voted to reopen and so did four others, and the question is now alive and open. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 4):

Answering as a moderator on Programmers, I had closed your question on Programmers as off-topic because it does not meet the criteria for being on-topic on Programmers.  Excerpt from the [Programmers Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help):

> Programmers Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for professionals and
>   students in software development and related fields who are interested
>   in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software
>   development.
>
> If you have a question about...
>
> ```
> software requirements
> software architecture and design
> algorithm and data structure concepts
> development methodologies and processes
> software engineering management
> quality assurance and testing
> software licensing
> ```
>
> and it is not about...
>
> ```
> general workplace issues, office politics, and job hunting (check out The Workplace instead)
> implementation issues, such as code fixes (ask on Stack Overflow instead)
> coding tools, such as compilers, debuggers, and IDEs (ask on Stack Overflow instead)
> what language/technology you should learn next, including which technology is better
> what project you should do next
> what book you should read next
> where to find a software library, tool or other resource
> product or service recommendations
> career advice, salary, or compensation
> personal lifestyle, including relationships and non-programming activities
> legal assistance
> ```
>
> ...then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Your question is clearly about an IDE falling under the mentioned criteria here:

> coding tools, such as compilers, debuggers, and IDEs (**ask on Stack Overflow instead**)

If you have any additional questions or concerns about your question closure on Programmers then I encourage you to ask a question on Programmers Meta for further guidance from moderators and the community.