# When is the new closing system going to be turned loose?

Tags: discussion, on-hold

I'm 3k on SO, and I'm anxious for the new closing/on-holding system to break out of its meta prison.

What is the ETA for the new system to come to other sites?

Comment: 6-8 weeks. What else?

Comment: @Oded I was expecting that. You can't be just a little more creative?

Comment: @Undo Give him 6-8 weeks to come up with something better.

Comment: Creativity leads to fun...and you know what we think about fun, don't you?

Comment: No. Creativity is not allowed - it is in the contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [the featured thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/212576), it'll be released sometime in next week (from 12th June). So, in all probability; it should be released in this week across the Stack Exchange network.

They are probably changing help-center and fixing other trivial issues which have been reported this week.

Comment: I think the point of this question is that this week is pretty much over, and yet it still isn't here yet.

Comment: @Servy Which is why I also mentioned that the team is fixing trivial issues reported regarding them.