# Can a moderator please reopen this specific question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I have an answer for [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787977/jquery-modal-dialog-box-not-working-in-google-chrome), but the question was closed because too narrow geographically. I think this is a broadly applicable question and should be reopened; the problem is a bug in the popular chrome to phone extension that messes up the JS on pages you view.

I would just leave a comment on the question, but I'm brand new here and don't have any rep.

If nobody will open it, can someone at least post in the comments section of that question that he should try disabling chrome to phone. There are documented probs with that extension, and my JS worked when I did that. Here's a link to the probs with chrome to phone: https://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/issues/detail?id=316.

Thanks.

Comment: How is Chrome to Phone related here?

Comment: Then post it on the comment.

Comment: @doubleDown Rep limit.

Comment: Reason I ask: if a bug in Chrome to Phone is the cause here, the issue is *definitely* too localized. I'll post your link, though.

Comment: Oops missed that bit about rep. Btw why was there an appeal to Jon Skeet in [javaL's final comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787977/jquery-modal-dialog-box-not-working-in-google-chrome#comment24222054_16787977)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it *is* too localized.

Not because it is only applicable to a specific moment in time or geography, but rather that it's too localized in that *no one will ever have that exact code & problem again*. Think about it - it's basically 'I have this error and this code. What's wrong?'

That's the very definition of too localized.

Comment: I agree that the question as written is too localized, but that's only bc the asker thinks there's a problem in his/her code. There isn't. The point of the question is, "hey, why is my JS not working in chrome but it is in all these other browsers, and btw I'm getting this specific error error." I was having the same prob with the same error, and my fix worked.

Comment: @Matt So the question *is* too localized. Therefore, it needs to be closed in its current state. Feel free to suggest an edit to improve it, though!

Comment: "no one will ever have that exact code & problem again." Except that the person answering has also seen that problem, and has a fix for it.

Comment: @Danack Hyperbole :) Would you say that it appeals to the broader audience of the Interwebs?

Comment: @Danack If you agree with the OP, go cast a reopen vote - who am I to stop you?

Comment: Oh, no thanks. It's still a rubbish question. I'm still looking forawrd to 'on hold, unclear what you're asking' as the original question just has "it doesn't work in chrome" as its 'question'.

Comment: @Danack [You and me both.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185367/when-is-the-new-closing-system-going-to-be-turned-loose)