# What happened to not a real question close vote

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I have seen new options for close vote screen:
[image]

I can't see *not a real question* and *too localized* here any more.

In many of question we have sen that "not a real question" will be the option in case user have not shown any research in his question. I have been using this option much during my close votes. But It's no more there. So What now?

Comment: oh, the irony...

Answer (score 4):

This is described in detail [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons), with clarification on how Stack Overflow's off-topic reasons are being adjusted for situations like this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185142/what-should-the-predefined-off-topic-reasons-be-for-stack-overflow).

Specifically,

[image: two new OT reasons]

...those two reasons are suitable for questions that fail to communicate a specific problem. Select the one most appropriate based on the type of question being asked.