# Are we accepting questions which will only help OP and not future visitors?

Tags: discussion

Just before few minutes, I saw that *too localized* option was removed from the close vote window, so are we accepting questions which are only helpful to OP and not the future visitors? Which option should be selected if op posts a question like..

> Please check this page - www.whatever.com..
>
> Footer is not showing up
>
> help me please..

So in this case, which close option should be selected from below?

[image]

Comment: You missed the memo: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes

Comment: But to be fair, yes, it's hard to determine from this list alone which reason to choose. After all, "off-topic" usually means "not programming related", and those questions *are* kind of programming related so why would they be off-topic, right?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn aaa thanks, let me read ;) though am keeping this question open as of now ... and yes, too localized was having a complete different meaning, off topic seems to be off-topic title for closing the question as too localized...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: ot reason]

That one seems right to me. Code he's written? Yup. Specific problem? Eh... Not so much. Code to reproduce it? No.

Comment: That option is listed under wrong title as [Bolt](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn) pointed out...

Comment: yeah, that's been discussed already. It's not perfect, but it comes closest to fitting in with what folks were already doing without making it *more* ridiculous.

Comment: Hope they fix it soon ;)

Comment: @Shog9 what about renaming/splitting off off-topic to site-specific (or "misc.")?

Comment: In the absence of this specific custom close reason, or one like it, I'd go with "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Its not as simple as just changing the heading, @Jan. OT provides for a reasonably-sane fallback when there's no consensus, when a migration fails, and when there are no site-specific reasons defined. We really need to see how this works in practice before making additional changes.