# Search Results list "on hold" questions as "closed"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, on-hold

The search results of SO list questions that are "on hold" as "closed". According to the new [closing changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) they should be displayed as **[on hold]**.

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ayes (open one of the first [closed]-results. It should be **[on hold]**)

Comment: Don't think it got anything to do with the elastic search itself, more with the display of search results. Tagged according to this.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ok no problem. Seems fine

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd actually...crap.  It *may* be an easy fix, looking when at a computer.

Comment: @Nick meant to write "actually it *does have* something to do with elastic search" thus putting it way on the bottom? Well, was hoping for the second part of your comment, good luck looking and hope it would be simple hack indeed. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This went out in a build last night, enjoy!

Comment: And it [happens again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302452/on-hold-posts-marked-as-closed-in-search-results)