# Advanced search term for "on hold" distinguished from "closed"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, on-hold

The advanced search keywords include “closed:yes” and “closed:no” for searching for questions that are closed and not closed, respectively.  Now that there is a new status, [on hold], is there a search term for such questions?  At the moment, it seems that “closed:yes” includes questions that are [on hold], as [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D%20%5Bxml%5D%20%5Brdf%5D%20closed:yes) illustrates: “[html] [xml] [rdf] closed:yes”.  I think that [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185960/225437) makes it clear that [on hold] questions appearing for “closed:yes” is intentional.

If there is any way for [on hold] questions to become [closed], other than the five day waiting period, it seems like it would be useful to be able to search for [on hold] questions without the [closed] questions.

I'm wondering whether there is a search term for [on hold] but not [closed] yet.  The advanced search tips don't show anything for it yet, but perhaps the tips just haven't been updated yet.

Comment: It's not a new status, just a name change, and that's only for the first 5 days after closure.

Comment: @Yannis Good point, and you're right, it's not a different status, just a different name for a few days.  Since the emphasis is on “these are still young enough to fix”, it still seems like it'd be nice to be able to search for them as distinct from older [closed] questions.  If there were date-based search terms, “onhold:yes” could just be a shorthand for “closed:yes age:<5days”.

Comment: There is a date based search term, `created`. You can get "on hold" questions by combining it with `closed. And, yes, it's undocumented, and [I've already ranted about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166835/can-we-update-the-search-tips-to-include-all-available-operators).

Comment: If I thought anyone would search for [on hold] questions to improve them, I'd support a distinguishing search option. But it's just not going to happen.

Comment: @Yannis I didn't know about the undocumented search features;  thanks for the link!

Comment: There is a Q&A with a snippet in it that lets you [find questions on hold on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261850/282094).