# How to put question on hold?

Tags: support, closed-questions, on-hold

I have seen that many questions are now marked `[on hold]`. I have already enough reputation to cast close votes on questions but I don't see how can I put questions on hold. How can I do it? Is it done within casting close votes, or is it a separate mechanism? If it is a separate mechanism, how much reputation do I need for it?

Answer (score 13):

You vote to close it.

Questions that get enough votes are put `[on hold]` for a period of several days. If they have not been reopened in that time, the `[on hold]` label will change to `[closed]`.

The exact rules and other closing changes are described in:

[Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)

Comment: Aha! Finally this is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Current several days is [five days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/187824).

Comment: @Tomas - see point 3 on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons

Comment: @hims056 - Yes. Though this _may_ change or be site specific. I wanted to keep the answer generic ;)

Comment: As I understand it, five days is now across all SE  sites. Of course, that may change over time, or on particular sites.

Comment: @Tomas Its to make clear that (the state formally known as) closed isnt a perminant state of affairs if the question is improved

Comment: What @RichardTingle said - essentially the idea is that people don't simply abandon a post ("on hold" suggests it can be salvaged, "closed" doesn't).

Answer (score 5):

"On hold" is just the fancy term these days for "closed less than five days ago". See [the blog post on the closing system redesign](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/?cb=1), and [the help centre entry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).