# question "on hold" still accepted an answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

According to [this meta question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) "on hold" questions will not accept answers.

But [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476622/calling-a-cuda-kernel-inside-another-cuda-kernel) was placed on hold at: 2013-07-05 07:58:51Z but accepted a new answer at: 2013-07-05 08:09:38Z

Is this expected behavior?

Note, for clarity, that the above meta question/answer reference also states "on hold" questions will behave identically to closed questions.

From what I can tell, closed questions cannot have new answers posted to them after they are closed. (I'm trying to avoid the use of the word "accept" here because I think it is an overloaded term.)

However the example SO question I linked allowed a new answer to be posted to the question after it was closed (more than 10 minutes after it was closed, from what I can tell.)

Comment: It is [by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48513/187824)

Comment: OK if that's an answer I would accept it or else mark this as a duplicate.