# Now that specific off-topic reasons are no longer displayed in the post, how about an auto-comment with the specific off-topic reason?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, automatic-comments

**Fact 1**

A custom off-topic reason generates an auto-comment with the reason for the close vote.

**Fact 2**

Specific off-topic close reasons are no longer displayed in the post itself, unless you are the poster or you have 3,000 reputation.

**Result**

Regular users (i.e. not the poster and not those who have 3,000 reputation) cannot see why a question was deemed to be off-topic unless it was closed with a custom off-topic reason.

**Problem**

This seems to be inconsistent. If we don't want them to know the specific reason why a question is considered off-topic, then they shouldn't be able to see it when there is a custom off-topic reason. If we do want them (or at least don't care if they are able) to see the specific reason why a question is considered off-topic, then they should be able to see it even if it was not a custom off-topic reason.

**Solution**

The system should generate an auto-comment for all off-topic reasons just like it does for custom off-topic reasons. This way anyone will be able to determine the specific off-topic reason by reading the comment, whether a custom reason was used or whether one of the existing specific reasons was used.

I am aware that the suggestion of auto-comments was made on at least two previous occasions ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214931/all-close-votes-should-add-an-auto-generated-comment) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191213/auto-add-comment-on-close-vote)). However, both of those suggestions were made at a time when the post itself displayed the specific off-topic reason to all viewers. This is no longer the case, and therefore auto-comments would serve a much greater purpose. Additionally, the discussion in the previous requests was primarily related to the time period before a question gets closed (i.e. during the voting process). Here I am primarily concerned with what happens *after* a question is successfully closed.

A concern mentioned in the previous discussions was that the identity of close-voters would be revealed via an auto-comment. Aside from the various possible ways to implement this without revealing anyone's identity, a custom off-topic vote and a duplicate vote already generate auto-comments that reveal the voter's identity. If it's not a problem in those cases, why should be a problem in the case of specific off-topic reasons?

In light of the above, can this idea be reconsidered?

---

This request is very different from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346516/i-can-no-longer-see-the-close-reason-i-chose). That is about no longer being able to see which close reason you yourself selected. This is about an auto-comment that would be generated on the question.

Comment: I think it'd be better for the specific reason to just be put back into the post notices for everyone - it'd be *much* less noisy than auto-comments everywhere.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I agree, nut I doubt that will happen given that they were deliberately taken out pretty recently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can no longer see the close reason I chose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346516/i-can-no-longer-see-the-close-reason-i-chose#comment1160780_346516)

Comment: I think they’re going to set it up so that moderators can choose the text each group sees: OP, users who can close/reopen, and everyone else. This is already done on Stack Overflow. See my [post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337104/323179) for the full picture.

Comment: @Rob That question is about being able to see your own close vote choice. I'm asking about an auto-comment.

Comment: @Rob The question you voted to close as a duplicate of is not an announcement. It is an unrelated question which is itself closed as a duplicate of a general announcement. (Also, my question doesn't necessarily relate to that announcement, as this issue already existed before the most recent changes.)

Comment: Alex, Yes, [read the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346516/i-can-no-longer-see-the-close-reason-i-chose#comment1160780_346516) that I edited in as the link: "4  - Possible duplicate of `Question Close Updates` - **now that there's an official announcement, reports and feature-request​s belong there. Better not to have info scattered all over the place** – Jenayah yesterday" - Once your rep is > ~2K it is expected that you know this, but I don't mind a single ping requesting a reminder if you are not active on this site - though that doesn't seem to apply in your case.

Comment: @Rob I see that comment, but that's not [the question that is proposed as the one this is a duplicate of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsOlG.png).