# Understanding why my questions got closed as "not constructive"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

What are the parameters of the question, that makes it not constructive?

There were these two questions I have made:

- [OCR of picture taken by camera (such as traffic sign)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647705/ocr-of-picture-taken-by-camera-such-as-traffic-sign)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170368/what-are-the-arguments-of-people-opposing-proposing-darts-named-constructors-and

One of them closed as not constructive and the second is on a good way to getting closed.

Are these questions fundamentally flawed, or it is just the way how I have asked them? And what is wrong with them? Wouldn't it be good idea to add some reason explanation to such closed questions?

Comment: Keep in mind that "not constructive" no longer exists as a close reason. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons-bye-bye

Comment: An explanation *is* added to closed questions. It's that gray box that appears underneath with all those words in it. Some of 'em are bold. And links.

Comment: As far as [the second question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170368/what-are-the-arguments-of-people-opposing-proposing-darts-named-constructors-and), I think it is a fair question, just not a good fit for Stack Overflow. I'd say it is appropriate for [Programmers.SE]; perhaps one of their mods or veteran users will happen by here and indicate whether or not they concur.

Comment: I think the fundamental issue is that you're asking open-ended and subjective questions. There's no right or wrong answer for your question regarding `Dart`, and your OCR question is quite broad and so it would be difficult to give an objective answer. As Cody Gray said, the `Dart` question itself isn't bad but it's not really suited to SO.

Comment: And the first question is not really a question. There are many questions in there, which more or less lead to a discussion, opinions, experiences, etc. That's far too forum-y.

Comment: @CodyGray that is not an explanation, that is some template text that sometimes makes no sense to me. Or at least, I do not understand how does it apply to the question I have asked.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys, so, now I understand that the problem with the first question is that it is too broad. I will have this on my mind in the future. Perhaps it would make more sense to me, if it would be possible to write some better explanation (like you have gave me now) to the closed questions. Not constructive sounds more WTF like than too broad for SO.

Comment: @SamuelHapak - There are now more options (including "too broad") when closing a thread so hopefully the reasons should be clearer from now rather than just a blanket "not constructive".

Comment: The problem with the first one is that it's too broad (you're asking *seven* questions by my count---you should only ask *one* per post) but also that you're asking for opinions ("Is it worth spending time", "Is the result good", "What are your experiences").

Comment: As for the second one, it's like straight from the [don't ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) part of help center: *"If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."*

Comment: @Juhana I hava no intent to participate in a discussion, I just want to understand the design decisions for Dart. I know there are reasons for and against, but I have never seen them explained in a detail. I do not want anyone to judge, which side has stronger reasons, just to see them explained.

Comment: OK, but that's still not a StackOverflow appropriate question.  That's still basically a discussion question - even if you don't specifically want discussion, what you want is to understand the history behind something; there's a reason most college history classes have discussion sections.  SO isn't a history class.  Each question should have one demonstrably correct answer.  Asking for the reasons behind something will almost inevitably involve discussion or disagreement, because unless there was a single person behind <whatever> and that person answers, the reasons are often not obvious.

Comment: @Joe Ok, I think I see your point. My question is, does it affect only SO questions, or also other sites? For example, reading the programmers site: "Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development." It is about conceptual questions and conceptual questions do not use to have one demonstrably correct answer.