# Not a question flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

Who hasn't seen a question which is not a real question? Many of them are pasted code and one line of explanation what peer wants. No question at all.

I'm curious why there is no flag for 'Not a question', while there is 'Not an answer' flag. I was thinking how to flag those 'questions' and I have no clue. I was flagging it as 'It needs moderation', but I think it would be much simpler to just flag it as 'Not a question'.

Do you think it's needed? Is it a big problem to add this flag?

Comment: There used to be such a flag, known as NARQ - it was replaced by what you see these days which is much more meaningful to the OP than just throwing "your question is bad" in his face. This let the OP fix the question, where before all he could do is wonder why it got closed.

Comment: I don't think that system is wrong, but there is a need for additional flag, so I can say that some 'question' is not a question. I don't want flag: "your question is wrong". I think that 'not a question' is describing a problem, such as 'not an answer' is

Comment: No it's not. From own experience, most questions closed as NARQ before falls into "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results".

Comment: Be careful with flagging questions as "not a question" or "needs moderation."  If I can't immediately see what's wrong with the question and choose an appropriate close reason, I often have to decline flags for not being specific enough.

Comment: @BilltheLizard thanks for advice, I'm trying to comment first and wait for peer reaction before flagging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can already flag such questions ([15 rep are required](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)). Even better we can choose a **specific reason** why this is no valid question:

> Flag → It does not belong here or is a duplicate → *choose a specific reason*

The new close reasons can be a bit odd at first. See [the explanations here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons-bye-bye)

Comment: But there is no option for 'question' which is programming request not a too broad, duplicate or whatever

Comment: @wudzik Off Topic `-->` "Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Comment: @Doorknob thanks for explanation

Comment: You can not flag for a specific reason its not in the pop up. (When flagging for off topic, I do not believe the subreason is kept with the flag. You are only casting a flag for off topic) You may only close for a specific reason.

Comment: @FDinoff: No, yuo can choose a specific off-topic reason when flagging.