# Is it possible to speed up migration?

Tags: feature-request, migration

The new close system puts questions [on hold] for a period of time (maybe a week?).  I think this is generally a good thing.  However, there are times when it would be nicer if there were no waiting period.  For example, sometimes a user will ask a question on stats.SE about the use of statistical software that is really a coding question rather than a statistical question.  I will ask them about this issue in a comment, and they will respond 'Oh, that makes sense, migrate my question to SO please'.  At this point, I will vote to close and other votes will often come in within a day or two.  Then, the OP needs to wait, though.  I always ask that they not cross-post, per SE policy, but if I were the OP, and I needed an answer fast, I would be tempted to cross-post rather than wait a week for my question to ultimately arrive on SO.  It seems like the old system didn't have this issue.  **Is it possible to speed up migration under the new system?**

Comment: Erm, if the verdict of the close is migration, isn’t it migrated automatically? Can you link to a question? (Stats.SE, for example, isn’t in the menu — it may have been suggested in a custom close reason, but the actual reason for migration was probably someone else’s moderator flag, which is the right way to take care of migration to sites not on that list, yes.)

Comment: @minitech, note that I'm referring to migration *from* stats.SE, not from SO. [This question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69065/frequency-table-comparison-using-r) was put on hold Sep 3, but is still on CV. The OP noted in comments that he would prefer to be migrated to SO. Fortunately, I provided an answer, so he has something to work w/. But I suspect he's hoping for a better answer (& will most likely get one on SO).

Comment: That question was closed as off topic with one of the predefined reasons. When people were selecting the close reason they need to pick "Belongs on another site" for it to get migrated. If the OP wants it to be migrated after it is closed he can flag it with other.

Comment: So is the issue that if you vote: `close -> belongs on another site -> SO`, then it gets migrated immediately, but if you vote: `close -> 'programming Q's belong on SO'`, then it has to wait 7 days? Is that the story here? If so, can we make the former path more salient so that it becomes the default?

Comment: @gung The post will never be migrated if you close with programming Question belong on SO (Your second option)

Comment: At P.SE we had a similar discussion with [Confusing Closing -> Off Topic dialog](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/confusing-closing-off-topic-dialog) - you likely need to talk to your moderators to modify the reasons.

Comment: That seems to be the answer, @MichaelT (& I've raised the issue on our meta), would you care to make it an 'official' answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @gung there you go (and I see you marked it).  You may also find the question where we refined the close reasons useful in the process - [What should our predefined off-topic reasons be?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5992/what-should-our-predefined-off-topic-reasons-be) - there were edits and comments and such, along with the community process of selecting them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As part of the [close reason changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons-bye-bye) the inital set of off topic reasons were rather, generic.  They also had the property of being confusing for people casting close votes thinking they were migration paths rather than off topic close.  For example, from Programmers.SE:

- Questions about specific programming problems encountered while
  writing code are off-topic, but can be asked on Stack Overflow.
- Questions about the use of general computer hardware or software are
  off-topic, but can be asked on Super User.
- Questions seeking career advice or help with office politics are
  off-topic here unless they're specific to the programming profession.
  If people in other professions face similar problems, ask about it on
  The Workplace Stack Exchange.
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
- Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

One of the interesting graphs that Shog9 presented in [an answer for P.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6107/40980) showed this confusion of migration targets and off topic reasons:

[image]

The purple line was questions that were migrated while the pale blue  line on the left was the one that was essentially "this belongs on Stack Overflow" off topic close.  You can see the first two data points in this chart shows much lower than the normal migration rate.

The appropriate thing to do is to raise the issue of the off custom off topic reasons with the moderators on your site to customize them from the initial batch.  This should give you less confusion about how to migrate and also provide you with, well, better close reasons that are applicable to your StackExchange.

Comment: Thanks, I like the graph & the detailed info, too.