# Adding answer text to "on hold" questions

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions

So this question here was put [on hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706603/parsing-numbers-in-words-one-thousand-two-hundred-into-its-numeric-equivale).

Subsequently to its closure, an answer was edited in by another person (not the OP) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19706603/revisions).

What exactly is the right thing to do in this situation?  Deleting the answer text from the question seems a bit rude to the person who went to the effort to write the answer.

Although I think in this case it is likely that the question may be reopened, is there a solution in the general case?

Comment: The question was "on hold", not closed :P http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rollback - answers should ***never*** be in the question. I have done that now.

(I have also voted to reopen, because I do believe that this was wrongly closed, but generally if a question is closed it's closed for a good reason. Gaming the system by editing one into the question is not a good thing.)

Comment: Agreed with the rollback, but I disagree about re-opening. I've found at least two good duplicates: [How to read values from numbers written as words?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/70161), [Is there a way to convert number words to integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/493174). Also, asking for solutions in any of multiple languages is problematic in my view; it seriously muddies the usefulness of the page for future searches.

Comment: You voted to reopen? What about questions "must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"? Also, possibly "too broad", given that OP can't pick one language. Not to mention the possible duplicates. Questions should preferably be closed for the correct reason, but once they're closed, don't open them again, just to close them again.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear; the question was not "Closed", it was "On hold". Changes were made recently specifically to handle this "question should be improved" process, to avoid being agressive to newbies.

The purpose of the site is to provide useful questions and answers. Edits were made to the question (by me) to try and be useful, without being a dupe (for example, I couldn't see an F# solution). Whether this fits the original OPs needs is questionable; but as dupes in other languages had been pointed out, it seems valid to make this an F#-specific version, so that StackOverflow now has an additional useful answer.

I agree the answer shouldn't be in the question, but StackOverflow (incorrectly, IMO) doesn't allow answers to on-hold questions, so it was a temporary measure while the question was in the process of being opened (and made a non-duplicate).

Let's not lose sight of the goal - to be helpful. If a question goes on-hold and is actively being improved to be a useful question/answer, it seems silly to stop people from posting answers. Common sense should be applied; if a question looks likely to be valid/re-opened, then the question is the only place to stash an answer to be helpful. This is a flaw in StackOverflow (or the over-zealous vote-closers), but surely it's better to be useful than not?

Comment: ["On hold" is just what "closed" is called for the first week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/). They are exactly the same in effect.

Comment: I salute the effort you put into improving the question, but I strongly disagree with the rest of this. The goal of the site is not to be helpful only in the short-term, it's to assemble a long-lived library of clear, broadly-applicable problem statements paired with equally intelligible and correct solutions. If a question _doesn't_ measure up, but gets answers anyways, what's the incentive for the asker to meet the standards? A certain amount of exclusivity is the means by which SO stays helpful into the future.

Comment: This question was "on hold" at the time of all of this. How does fixing the question to be valid and adding an answer not help in the long term? It's the exact purpose of this site.

Comment: I disagree with the idea of answering closed questions, not with improving a question.