# Close reason missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

On this new update, I tried voting to close as off topic, due to not being on topic for the reasons stated in the help centre. I have seen other questions closed for that reason, so the reason hasn't disappeared. It's missing when I choose flag, or close as off topic for another reason from the question menu

This question does not appear to be about (site name) within the scope defined in the help centre

Version 0.1.68

First screen:

> [image]

Second screen:

> [image]

Comment: Do you have a picture? and did you check the related questions in the side-bar?

Comment: there is no pure off-topic close reason... you have to select one of the sub-options, which vary on each site

Comment: I'm on the app, as I only have a computer at work. If this is a duplicate, please close it. As for a picture, how can I upload a screenshot from the app?

Comment: @CanadianLuke no idea if this is a dup yet because I'm not sure what the issue is yet.  Which option (specifically) did you select to close AFTER you picked off-topic?  We are not permitted to close questions as off-topic without selecting one of the sub-options (such as "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance" on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Power + volume down takes a screen shot on _most_ Android phones.

Comment: I got the pictures, can I post a drop box link and have someone upload it here? Otherwise I'll have to wait till tomorrow when I'm at work

Comment: @CanadianLuke yes, put wherever you can and someone will embed into your post.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6cd4nq7ucvf0qvx/2013-11-24-14-23-21.jpg and https://www.dropbox.com/s/agx374x580mxp46/2013-11-24-14-23-42.jpg

Comment: Well that's exactly what I see too. What you think is missing?

Comment: See edit above, Al

Comment: @CanadianLuke I think you need to explain in detail how to reproduce... (1) you select "flag", (2) you select "should be closed for another reason", (3) you pick "off-topic"...  then what?

Comment: "This question does not appear to be about (site name) within the scope defined in the help centre" used to be an option to pick

Comment: @CanadianLuke it's not anymore... you have to select one of the subreasons (screen shot #2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, I believe you are missing a step:

The process you are using is:

1. Select flag (or close)
2. (If flagging, get to the close reason dialog)
3. Select off-topic

This is where you are running into your problem.

You are expecting to see "This question does not appear to be about (site name) within the scope defined in the help center" as an option, but it doesn't exist anymore.

You have to select one of the options shown.  These options are custom reasons configured on a per-site basis, but if you can't find an option for the specific question, then you can click "Other" and enter your own custom reason.  The custom reason will appear as a comment on the question.

Comment: See if I can comment here... when did that reason disappear?

Comment: @CanadianLuke technically, it was late June.  But for flagging, you weren't allowed to select the suboptions initially (so all flags were "off-topic".  It wasn't until a few months later that the flag dialog was changed to require you select a suboption.

Comment: @CanadianLuke this question covers the changes in more detail: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/182513

Comment: Alright, thanks for the link