# Why do duplicate questions go through a different closing process?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, moderation, on-hold

Why is it possible for a question to be closed in two different ways?

This one was closed by a single vote (a diamond user):

> [image]

This one took 5 votes but one of them is a diamond user:

> [image]

Would the second question be closed as soon as Marc Gravell clicked on close?
Maybe duplicates are different but I'm pretty sure I remember voting for a question to be put on hold as a duplicate. So:

- Is a diamond user's vote always the final vote to a closing process?
- What makes that a question need to be marked as a duplicate by a moderator instead of being on hold as duplicate as for user vote.

Comment: Diamond moderators votes are binding; if Tim Stone had not voted yet, Marc's vote would still have put the question on hold. In effect, they close directly, everyone else closes indirectly through voting.

Comment: Marking a question as a duplicate doesn't ever put it on hold. That's indeed different about duplicates.

Comment: So if a diamond mod judge that you are posting a dupe, it will only take his vote. Good to know

Comment: Diamond mods don't have close votes... they have close powers.

Comment: From the [closing FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question): *Moderators may close any question (regardless of their reputation)*; other users **vote** to close instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Diamond mods can't *vote* to close a question (per se), their vote directly closes it. Unless it's perfectly clear that the question should be closed, it is usually closed by 5 normal users with the privilege.

Answer (score 9):

You have two questions here:

1. Questions are always put on hold first, but instead of 'closed' or 'put on hold', duplicate questions use the wording 'marked as duplicate'. See [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons):

   > Questions closed as dupe show as [duplicate], not [closed]

   Note that the 'on hold' state is just a temporary label; for the first 5 days, the label 'on hold' is used instead of 'closed', except of course for duplicates, which don't use 'closed' at all.
2. Diamond moderators don't *vote*. They close directly. It doesn't matter if there are 0 or 4 or any other number of votes already on the question. From [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question):

   > - Users with at least 250 rep may **vote to close** their own questions
   > - Users with at least 3,000 (500 on Beta sites) may **vote to close** any questions (see limits below)
   > - Moderators **may close any question** (regardless of their reputation)

   emphasis mine.

The fact that Oded closed that first question as a dupe directly, is just a coincidence (and Oded is fast). No ordinary users had a chance to vote on that post just yet.