# How to fetch the close reason for a closed question using voteTypeId

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons

How can I  find, from the data in the Stack Exchange datadump, the close reason if a question is voted to close by using the `VoteTypeId` column?.

Answer (score 5):

The close reason is not directly in a table or field, it is stored in the `PostHistory` table in the `comment` field when the post gets closed. Notice that since June, 2013 the Votes table doesn't have the close votes anymore but you don't need that to answer your question.

from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100):

```
If PostHistoryTypeId = 10, this field contains the CloseReasonId of the close reason:
 1: Exact Duplicate
 2: Off-topic
 3: Subjective and argumentative
 4: Not a real question
 7: Too localized
 10: General reference
 20: Noise or pointless (Meta sites only)
New close reasons:
 101: Duplicate
 102: Off-topic
 103: Unclear what you're asking
 104: Too broad
 105: Primarily opinion-based
```

You can see there two Off-topic reasons, one with code 2 and one with 102. The difference between them is the timeframe when they were introduced. You would see posts with closereason 2 if they were [closed before June 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons?rq=1) after that time you would see the 102 closereason if off-topic was chosen.

So you basically do this:

```
select ph.postid
     , ph.comment as closereason
     , ph.text as voters
from PostHistory ph 
where ph.posthistorytypeid = 10
```

The [sede query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/178791/close-reason-for-closed-postes-over-votes) shows you what it looks like.