# Should opinion-seeking questions with many answers be reworded or left as-is?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

I have an [opinion-seeking question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/715/how-old-is-old-enough-for-a-child-to-have-their-ears-pierced) that is several years old and just recently was marked as on-hold. The on-hold status requests I re-word my question, but since there are already so many answers that *some* may find value in -- and thus should not be deleted -- I am leaning towards leaving the question as is (i.e., on-hold or changing to closed, but just not deleted).

Alternatively, I could change the question to something like, "What are some cultural norms for piercing child's ears?" or "What are some pros and cons to piercing a child's ears at a young age?", but then is it odd that there are opinion-based answers with many votes?

Comment: @gnat - Thanks for the related/duplicate post. The question and answers on there are what I was looking for, although I wonder if my question should remain since it is about opinion-based questions instead of not-constructive ones.

Comment: FWIW these reasons are about the same, see [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/165773)