# Misuse because of... misuse? Non duplicate question marked as duplicated

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm talking about this question: [Avoid developers to see included plain text code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862784/avoid-developers-to-see-included-plain-text-code).

It was marked as duplicated, while in the comments we can clearly see it's not a duplicate. So the users with the 'power' to close questions overlooked at it and decided it was a dup. He's not looking for obfuscation, he was looking for something else. I had some sort of answer but the answers were closed.

Did I act correctly? I don't have enough rep as to reopen the question, but I thought I had an actual answer so I tried to answer in the comments, which I know it's a bad practice.

End result: the user was happy and I answer the question. My question is, **how to avoid this situation in the future?**. I edited the title and said in the edit note that it was not a dup, although nothing happened. It was incorrectly marked as a duplicate, and while I had an answer for a correct question, I couldn't answer properly.

**What is recommended in this case?** I think allowing to tag the people that closed the question in the comments would be a good idea.

Comment: Don't fret, a closed question isn't "done". This happens all the time and StackOverflow is actually very civil in that regard, compared to some of the other SE sites. [This meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497) discusses aspects what what you encountered. With enough rep you'll be able to act yourself. But yeah, closing a question sometimes happens too quickly.

Comment: As an aside: didn't [fardjad already answer the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862784/avoid-developers-to-see-included-plain-text-code/15862897#15862897) you'd like to post?

Comment: @Arjan , only kind of. A web service is a too broad definition, I wanted to give a case-specific solution with one example along with what I tried in the past for a similar problem and didn't work (so he doesn't go down that road) and a proper list of what could go wrong with that solution. But as I noted, I couldn't do so in the comment.

Comment: It can be prevented by the OP clearly stating his requirements and not making too many assumptions how they should be addressed.  A "problem" with SO is that you'll get what you ask for.

Comment: It was reopened and I answered, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You've done the right thing.

Sometimes a question can get closed quite rapidly and it requires supplementary explanation in order to get it reopened (like you've done). Once you have enough rep you could cast a reopen vote yourself which will get the question on the reopen review queue, but until then posting a question on Meta is your only real option (this isn't something you should flag a mod for except as a last resort).

Of course this is no guarantee that it won't get closed again - I don't know if there is any safeguard to pick up questions that are bouncing between the close and reopen queues. Be prepared to get it reopened, and maybe edit in the reasons why you don't consider it a duplicate (rather than having the reasons buried in the comments).

Comment: I did edit it with the reasons why I don't consider it a duplicate. Question is, when I did, did someone get notified? Or it just looked a bit prettier without any use? For now, it was reopened and I could answer, but what if this situation happen in the future?

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos No, nobody except the OP gets notified when you make the edit, although if you have insufficient rep it will simply be a suggested edit and will need to go through the review queue. If the edit is buried within the post somewhere then close vote reviewers may not see it.