# Make question status a hyperlink to its explanation

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, post-notices

I just saw a question marked with a status with which I am unfamiliar, [on hold].  With a little searching, I discovered [what it is all about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-replace-close-with-on-hold-for-the-first-five-d).  However, it would be convenient if its status were a hyperlink to an explanation.

[image: close banner with text: "on hold as primarily opinion-based…"; "on hold" isn't linked but it should be]

Comment: I agree, or at least put a link in the description. That should reduce the number of new users coming to meta to ask "Why is my question put on hold" or "What does on hold mean?"-esque questions.

Comment: @raven: Is that a better tag for you? Please don't keep re-creating the [meta-tag:status] tag. It's ambiguous and not useful.

Comment: Voting to close as no longer reproducible, since the dialog now looks very different from this - it says "closed" rather than "on hold", and the *closure reason*, *does* get linked.