# How long will a question be in on-hold status?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, on-hold, time-limit

When will a question be closed in Stack Overflow, i.e. transform from "on hold" to "closed"?

I searched about it on Meta and found [five days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-replace-close-with-on-hold-for-the-first-five-d) as the answer; but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423642/how-to-include-external-php-file-laravel-4) has been on hold for almost a week.

Comment: That's weird...

Comment: 5... business days?

Comment: I thought it was 5 days as well. Maybe 6-8...days?

Comment: I'd say check it again tomorrow. Remember the time period will be from the time it was put On Hold, not the time it was actually asked in the first place, so I'd guess we've got another few hours or so until it is fully closed.

Comment: @Jonw It was put on hold at 2013-07-**02** 16:55:44Z; it is now 2013-07-**09** ~12:53:30Z.

Comment: [Fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173497/152859) ;-)

Comment: @michaelb958, [it's not a bug, it's a feature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/234170/756941)

Comment: I'd give it 6-8 weeks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<strike>Questions remain [on-hold] for 7 days.</strike>

This is something that can be changed per-site, though they are all defaulting to 7 days at the moment.

Update: The "on hold" period was briefly set to 7 days, but it has been changed back to 5 days, which was the original intent. This time period is set to match the window during which an edit by the OP sends an "on hold" question to the reopen review queue.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: so, it's not a bug.then why can't you add the tag status-by-design?

Comment: @Azik i think he will do it after 2013-07-09 16:55:44Z. Then are the 7 days over.

Comment: Hmmm, in this case the Help Center [sections](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) should be updated to reflect this (currently it says 5 days)

Comment: @Azik technically, the question title is asking a simple question: "How long?" There is no status-bydesign needed here, since the answer is: 7 days. Now, the body of the question does challenge the meta answer (and by extension the help center), and perhaps the title (and even tags) should be updated to reflect that it is a bug in the documentation, not a bug that a question has been on hold longer than 5 days.

Comment: @doubleDown, good catch

Comment: ... @Azik or [meta-tag:support]?

Comment: @juergen Yes, here