# Introducing a mechanism to remove unwanted up- and down-votes from posts?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes

I've come across some posts on **Stack Overflow**, both questions and answers, which have been down-voted without any comments, but answers may be ok or good.

This one example [image: screen shot of post]

Sometimes I've seen somebody down-voting  all the answers to a question like a serial down-voter. So I found this link [Should a user be forced to add a comment when they vote to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29531/should-a-user-be-forced-to-add-a-comment-when-they-vote-to-close) and I found it helpful.

Same case applies for up-voting also, users don't read the post completely and would up-vote it and these votes (up/down) will decide the quality of the post.

Yeah, I agree that the down-vote can be cancelled out by another up-vote or vice versa, but what if a good answer was down-voted and someone else up-voted it, so that answer's score will be 0 where it should be 1.

So what I actually want to know is whether there is anything (that can be) done to remove unwanted votes after somebody validates it who has a good reputation plus his/hers tags match with that of the post and he/she is not given a provision to validate their own votes, so that we can ensure the quality of the question and answers?

**PS : The image given above is just an example not the example**

Comment: No. *Every* downvote is unwanted by the author of the post...

Comment: in his prespective!!

Comment: Questions that are duplicates should not be asked in the first place but if they are they should be closed, not answered.  As such the answer is not useful, which merits a down vote. Asking a low quality duplicate isn't helpful either which is again a reason to down vote. None of the down votes on the examples presented are unwarranted and as such shouldn't be removed.

Comment: @rene I agree with you on that point, but what to be done when some one is down voting a post without even looking into it. That can be considered as unwanted. I've edited my question.

Comment: Who's going to validate it?

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s

Comment: already users are given provision to review the quality of questions and answers, can something like that be introduced to validate them (based on the tags matching with the post and that of user)

Comment: Experienced users are given provision to review the question quality of a stuff by new users. Voting is disabled in triage as otherwise those posts were just downvoted. Your proposal will ensure more downvotes, not fewer.

Comment: No I was saying like giving users the provision review the votes so that they can vote for it or against and based on votes either the reviewed vote can be kept or removed

Comment: If you show people experienced in tags bad questions or duplicates that show no research, the result is more downvotes, not fewer.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran I'm much more worried about the users that upvote posts without looking into it. The statistics so far show that happens much more frequently then down voting.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran The way for an experienced user to “remove” a downvote is to apply an upvote. That’s the only way. The original downvoter’s vote should never be invalidated, except in extreme circumstances (eg fraud backed by solid evidence), or you undermine the entire concept of voting. Everyone’s vote has equal weight, and no one gets more than a single vote. This is how the system generates consensus on the quality of a post (and what makes the SO model so overwhelmingly successful in the first place).

Comment: "But what I actually want to know is that whether is there any thing (that can be) done to remove unwanted down votes" - What can be done about unwanted upvotes?  What if fair for downvotes should apply to upvotes.   " I was saying like giving users the provision review the votes so that they can vote for it or against and based on votes either the reviewed vote can be kept or removed" - The users who perform reviews, are those same users, who issue downvotes.  So your going to have users review their own votes?

Comment: @Ramhound I've edited the question

Comment: "what if the an good answer was down voted and someone else up voted it, so that answer score will be 0 where it should be 1." - I have seen that happen maybe once in 6 years at SU.

Comment: @Ramhound My view of that scenario is that one person disagreed that it was a “good answer” in the first place, and one person agreed it was a good answer, so the answer score *should be zero* by definition. Not 1. There is no way to appeal to some Platonic ideal of a “good answer” and judge votes on that basis; rather we judge “good answers” on the basis of votes. The question you quote from the OP has causality the wrong way around.

Answer (score 9):

I think the tricky thing here is *unwanted*.

Clearly there's something the voter hates about the question - perhaps it's too simple aka "lack of research" and sometimes answering questions that are poor, encourages more poor questions, so some users downvote some answers too.

If a vote is *truely* unwanted - a vote can be retracted after an edit, presumably to fix specific issues. The question itself though, is a mix of "explain this concept" and "why was this added?". It's just not very good.

So in this case, the votes were wanted, and in some cases, someone may choose to edit/fix up a post to, as you've said, "remove an unwanted downvote". However we leave this to the voter.

Serial downvotes are a different kettle of fish, and invalidating votes is either automatic in extreme cases, or needs a SE staffer for a reason.